# How much dose of mosquito saliva does it need to poison a normal human adult to death, if ever possible?

Tags: death, poison, dose

Image that a normal human adult gets bited by thousands of individual mosquitoes continuously. Will that human adult be killed by the poison(if any) contained in the mosquito saliva injected to the blood stream?